# return same product with multiple id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now I'm returning a product by passing a `code` over url

```
class Product(APIView):
    def get_product(self, code):
        try:
            prod = ProductModel.objects.get(code=code)
            return prod
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, code, format=None):
        product = self.get_product(code)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

url

```
path('product/<code>/', views.Product.as_view()),
```

model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    category = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    marketing_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

this will return product if it's in the database, simple stuff but now I've added a JSON field in the ProductModel with multiple codes `["05017303032619", "05017303032626"]`, so I want to check do I have this codes and still return the item, basically return the same item by passing one of this codes over url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) instead of a JSONField for that.

**models.py**

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Product(models.Model):
    code = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```py
class Product(APIView):
    def get_product(self, code):
        try:
            return ProductModel.objects.filter(code__contains=code).first()
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, code, format=None):
        product = self.get_product(code)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I need to experiment, the problem, for me is that in `json` field I have only a list of keys, will update with the model

Comment: So, basically, you're saving a list of ids. Is that right? And you're using PostgreSQL, I assume?

Comment: yes, exactly, so it's just like I've posted `["05017303032619", "05017303032626"]`, and it can vary from 2 to 30

Comment: ah, yes, good, I've tried with `__in` lookup, but yes I totally forgot about this